# Is a wet/dry shop vacuum (5HP) noisier than a 3/4HP dust collector?

Tags: dust-collection

I have a 5HP vacuum that is connected to a Ridgid 3650 table saw. It seems that it is not perfect and sawdust is still present on the floor even after minor work.

I was thinking about buying a 3/4 portable dust collector and trying to see if this will improve the situation
https://www.busybeetools.com/products/craftex-mini-portable-dust-collector-3-4hp.html

I have read various posts by others who tried this and the situation is not improving radically. The dust collector is on sale now so I would buy it as a permanent solution (I am using the vacuum for many other things) and if the noise is lower I would buy the dust collector.

Is a dust collector less noisy than a vacuum?

Comment: This depends on the installation. A HF Dust collector mounted tightly against the wall in the studs may make significantly less noise than it being on its wheeled stand. The wall absorbes the vibrations.

Comment: Unrelated to your query, were you aware than the "5HP" rating on your vacuum is nonsense? No standard voltage can actually create this horsepower. I believe the true limit is actually somewhere between 1.5 and 2. Numerous class-action suits relating to this in various fields, including against Shop Vac and Black & Decker (Craftsman).

Comment: I have 4" dust collection from the cabinet of my table saw, but still have a problem with dust coming from many locations.  There is some dust thrown on the top of the table surface as the blade rotates.  More is coming from the curved opening in the cabinet where the blade height adjustment wheel rotates, and more still comes from any of the other openings in the cabinet collection cavity.  I have tried a number of different methods to try and control dust leaking out, but found the most effective dust collector is still a broom after I am done.

Comment: You'll have to check actual specs, which is hard because different manufacturers will report differently. (See, HP, above.) Chances are the dust collector will be less whiny and high pitched than the vac. With either device, there are strategies to muffling the noise... earplugs coupled with ear defenders bring a lot of noise down. You can also build a partial muffling wall around whichever dust collector you've got. One last thing, unrelated to what you're asking: the dust deputy type separators work wonders to keep large shavings/ chips out of the final dust collector bin.

Comment: I think it may be unrealistic to avoid dust altogether. Nothing can do that. The dust collector lets you just close up the bag and go every 20 minutes, rather than have to stop to fill the bag. End of the day it's a wood shop, dust is par for the course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dust collectors are high cfm with lower negative pressure, where as a shop vac is lower cfm and higher negative pressure. Most of the large shop vacs have been more noisy or at least a more irritating sound then my small dust collector. That one appears to be the same as the one I have from Harbor Freight, it has worked well for the limited amount of use it has had. Draw back does not catch the very fine particles. ***Do Not*** use a small hose but rather use a 4" hose with an adapter if necessary.

Comment: how did you small the problem of small particles. I am assuming you are referring to filtering as "catching" that it is doing that at the dust collector level, correct?